# Tensorflow building error

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I got this error while building Tensorflow 1.1.0

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: /home/bishal/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bishal/798d6395d959361055d9b5ddcd7dcd45/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/closure/testing/phantomjs_test.bzl:31:10: name 'set' is not defined
ERROR: /home/bishal/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bishal/798d6395d959361055d9b5ddcd7dcd45/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/closure/private/defs.bzl:27:16: name 'set' is not defined
ERROR: /home/bishal/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bishal/798d6395d959361055d9b5ddcd7dcd45/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/closure/compiler/closure_js_binary.bzl:216:13: name 'set' is not defined
ERROR: /home/bishal/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bishal/798d6395d959361055d9b5ddcd7dcd45/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/closure/filegroup_external.bzl:23:16: name 'set' is not defined
ERROR: error loading package '': Extension 'closure/filegroup_external.bzl' has errors
Building: no action
```

I've used `bazel 0.16.0` for this. If this issue is because of not proper version of bazel, which version do I have to use to solve this issue?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505614/tensorflow-and-bazel-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use [Bazel 0.5.4](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/tag/0.5.4) to build Tensorflow 1.1.0. Please note that 0.5.4 is very old -- it's 0.16.0 as of time of writing this answer.

Do you need to specifically build Tensorflow 1.1.0?

Comment: Yes. I've to build Tensorflow 1.1.0. 
Thank you for your suggestion. I'll try building with Bazel 0.5.4.